# Javascript variable scope with prototype

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I got stuck while coding and searching on for the past few hours hasn't helped me understand the following issue.

I have the following code:

```
var HomeController = function(){
    this.hello = "Welcome on the homescreen";
    this.user = null;
};

HomeController.prototype.setInterface = function(){

    var self = this;
    var api = new API();

    // Set user info
    var data = api.getUserInfo();

    data.done(function(userdata){
        $("#player").text("Welcome back, " + userdata.name + "!");
        self.user = userdata;
    });

    console.log(this.hello);
    console.log(this.user);
};
```

and I would like to make the user object as an property of the homecontroller.

I read about the use of the self variable, because context within the function would change but it does not seem to work here and I'm baffled.

The object contains data, it's not empty inside the function.

If it try to console log the following code, I get the following results:

```
Welcome on the homescreen
null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not the *where*, it's the ***when***. `console.log` inside your `done` callback as well and observe the timing...

Comment: Geez, you're right. I see what I've done wrong... thank you.